Finding illegal address references
I got some code and should integrate it in a legacy project with plain old C. The code could be compiled and didn't show problems in the first stage. But sometimes the program crashes. I found the problem by removing any parts of the additional code until the crash didn't occur anymore. But that is cumbersome and ... because it's based on undefined behavior it's also undefined if I can detect the error.
Here is the condensate of the errorneous code:
typedef struct Serial Serial;

typedef struct Foo
{
    Serial *tx;
    Serial *rx;
} Foo;

void InitComm(Foo *foo, Serial rx, Serial tx)
{
    foo->rx = &rx;
    foo->tx = &tx;
}

Foo g_foo; 
Serial g_rx, g_tx;

void TaskFunc(void)
{
    InitComm(&g_foo, g_rx, g_tx);
    // do some other stuff with g_foo.rx ...
}


The Serial objects are passed as value. The fix is to change the signature of InitComm to  InitComm(Foo *foo, Serial *rx, Serial *tx) and handover the addresses of the Serial structs. Taking the address of stack variables is allowed here as long as the address is used only in the function. But it is not allowed if the reference's lifetime exceeds the function run time, i.e. the return-statement.
Is there a way to detect such errors more efficient than with a code review?
Edit:
I used CppCheck as static code analysis tool. But it doesn't find it.
Some other additional info: Target machine 80186 (@CHIP), Compiler: Paradigm C++ Professional, Host OS Windows 10.

Maybe time to stub in more assert statements as well as look into a build where deallocated memory gets stomped with some value to shake out use-after-free bugs. What does Valgrind say?

Static analysis tools might be able to handle this.

So you're looking for c linting tools? https://github.com/caramelomartins/awesome-linters you've identified the problem, and it's bad practice. So you're looking for a tool to find that bad practice in particular? What would be a good answer to this question?

Some of the usual tools for recognition and tracing of invalid addresses are Valgrind and AddressSanitizer.  The latter is a tool built into some compilers that, when engaged, creates binaries instrumented for address checking.  The latter is an external program that monitors the execution of untooled binaries.

As far as static analysis goes, your compiler is the most basic tool.  Turn up the warning options all the way, and pay attention to the resulting diagnostics.  If the legacy project is sloppy then you may need to deal with diagnostics not related to your current effort, but make sure you understand the nature of every diagnostic before dismissing it.  Who knows, you might even find a flaw or two in the legacy project this way -- I've certainly done similar myself.

You say you're writing C code, but you name a C++ compiler.  C and C++ are different languages. C code requires a C compiler.

When you say "Target machine 80186" and "Host OS Windows 10", do you mean to say that you are cross compiling?  Because Windows 10 absolutely does not run on 80186 cpus.  It does, of course, run on recent x86_64 CPUs, including in 32-bit (x86) mode, but that's a whole different ball game.

@JohnBollinger Yes, it's a target compiler for that embedded device. And the product Paradigm C++ Compiler supported the languages C and C++. Meanwhile the compiler is not supported anymore. https://web.archive.org/web/20200605044350/https://www.devtools.com/

I couldn't find a list of the compiler options it supports. The Paradigm C++ Quick Start Guide seems to refer to the built-in help to get information about compiler options  :-(

Perhaps you could use CodeChecker that combines many of the most popular static analysis tools - or run the listed tools separately one-by-one to see if any of those catches the problem.

GCC 12+ has -Wdangling-pointer which detects this and is included in -Wall (you should always compile your code with -Wall -Wextra honestly):
<source>: In function 'InitComm':
<source>:14:13: warning: storing the address of local variable 'tx' in '*foo.tx' [-Wdangling-pointer=]
   14 |     foo->tx = &tx;
      |     ~~~~~~~~^~~~~
<source>:11:43: note: 'tx' declared here
   11 | void InitComm(Foo *foo, Serial rx, Serial tx)
      |                                    ~~~~~~~^~
<source>:11:43: note: 'foo' declared here
Compiler returned: 0

Godbolt link.

Ach, my answers are always too slow. +1 for FGITW.

Ok. Do I assume correctly, that it will be necessary to bring the entire project into a form that makes it compatible with GCC to use GCC to find errors? The Paradigm is rather dated and has a lot of incompatibilities, e.g. NEAR and FAR pointers because of the segmented memory model of the 80186. There is also an RTOS involved where no GCC pendant is available.

@harper Unfortunately yes, that is the downside of this solution. I don't know much about C static analysis tools. I know that CodeQL can detect this for sure if you write the appropriate query, but that still requires compiling a database (you might be able to do it with your current setup without changing compiler though).

As per gcc 12 or later, with all warnings enabled (-Wall -Wextra -pedantic), points out the bugs:

warning: storing the address of local variable 'tx' in '*foo.tx' [-Wdangling-pointer=]

-Wdangling-pointer specifically is part of -Wall.
-fsanitize=undefined can also spot various such bugs if you are lucky.
